# Confused about Angular2 promise

Tags: javascript, angular

I have very simple code , But I am not able to understand it.

I have a service which returns current Username

so I am doing following to get logged username and display on webpage. Please note current logged in user is "demo"

```
 this.userData.getUsername().then(value  => {
this.username = value ;   
console.log("Inside -->" + value);
});
console.log("Outside -- >" + this.username);
```

So now when I run this code. I do NOT get username in this.username

This is the output of console.log
`Outside -- >undefined
 Inside -->demo`
Shoulnd't this display 'demo' in both case. (inside and outside)
Why outside is undefined ??

Please help me understand this.

Comment: It's because the call is asynchronous.  It's starts running the `getUsername()` method, but while it's running it continues on.  So it hits the Outside log first, where `this.username` is still undefined, then the method finishes and you get the Inside log

Comment: Its nothing related to Angular 2. This is how asynchronous call works, [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

This is an async call that returns later

```
this.userData.getUsername().then(value  => {
  this.username = value ;   
  console.log("Inside -->" + value);
});
```

In the meantime execution continues here

```
console.log("Outside -- >" + this.username);
```

When the async call completes eventually the `Promise` executes the function

```
value  => {
  this.username = value ;   
  console.log("Inside -->" + value);
}
```

that was passed earlier.

Comment: Thanks. then how do I get username in  global variable (this.username) ?

Comment: This is what your code is doing already. What you seem to be confused about is what happens when. `this.username = value;` is executed much later then `console.log("Outside -- >" + this.username);`

Comment: Got it. I just got confused and did not code next step. I am actually getting correct value in the variable. Should have just trusted myself .